# Javascript / jQuery replace last word in input box in tamil language?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tamil, indic

I need to replace last word from input value

Im using this code,

```
Get_value =$(input).val();
new_word= "new word";

function ReplaceLastWord(Get_value, new_word) {
 return Get_value.replace(/\w*$/, new_word);
}

$(input).val(ReplaceLastWord(Get_value, new_word));
```

Its working, but only for english... i am using tamil laguage in input

```
$(input).val()="கோச்மேடிக்ஸ் ச்னக்க்ஸ்";
```

For this language i need use this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
     var lastWord = function(inputString,newstring) {
     inputString=inputString.replace((""+inputString).replace(/[\s-]+$/,'').split(/[\s-]/).pop(),newstring)
     alert(inputString);
};

lastWord("கோச்மேடிக்ஸ் ச்னக்க்ஸ்",'hi');
```

​
​

​[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5WgK/3/)

here inputString is input value and and newstring is word to replace with.

if this will help you mark this as answer

Comment: I cant understand this code, how to implement... which is input and which variable gives output from above program? can you please sent the program clearly

Comment: @Dhamu1 i have updated the code and attach demo also please have a look now

Comment: This both are only removing the last word, i need to replace the last word with new word. can you please make this?

Comment: i need to replace the last word with **new word**.Example : கோச்மேடிக்ஸ் ச்னக்க் to => கோச்மேடிக்ஸ் Get

Answer (score 0):

```
function ReplaceLastWord(Get_value, new_word) {
 return Get_value.substring(Get_value.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1) + new_word;
}
```